# Adding a favicon to an HTML file without a host?

Tags: html

I am trying to add a favicon to an HTML file. The icon works when I view it locally on my laptop but once I upload the assignment to my instructor the icon is not there. Do I need to set the href attribute to a link?

HTML:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon_io/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: What do you mean without a host? How would anyone else view it if it only exists on your laptop?

Comment: @j08691 yeah sorry I'm new to coding and if it sounds confusing, what I meant was that I'm am trying to add a favicon without having it be hosted online if that makes any sense? I understand that I am the only one that can view it since it's saved locally. It's an assignment for school and I've tried to submit the HTML file along with the icon file without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include your favicon in your folder named `favicon_io` and name your favicon `favicon.ico`

Or

Just drop your icon in your root folder where your `index.html` and change your href to

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />   "`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add your code in the header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon_io/favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- body content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Imports an icon to represent the document.

Example: `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

Comment: Thank you Milot!

Answer (score 1):

Double check the href path in your favicon link tag and make sure the link tag is placed in the  of your code.

If this doesn't work, use Chrome dev tools and open the Network tab. Check to see if the favicon asset is properly loaded into the DOM.

Also double check to make sure the favicon image asset is included in the submission of your homework assignment to your professor.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of other common types you'll come across. For example, a link to the site's favicon:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

There are a number of other icon rel values, mainly used to indicate special icon types for use on various mobile platforms, e.g.:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-icon-114.png" type="image/png">
```

> The HTML External Resource Link element () specifies
> relationships between the current document and an external resource.
> This element is most commonly used to link to stylesheets, but is also
> used to establish site icons (both `"favicon"` style icons and icons
> for the home screen and apps on mobile devices) among other things.

Add your code in header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Document Title</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***[Link: The External Resource Link element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)***